# Windows 10 bug options disappeared in right click mouse

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-shell

I can't create new folders in **any disk drives** either with "right-click" or the "New Folder" button.

I don't know when and how this problem started, but I maybe when I connected in my Microsoft Account. Other possible reason is when I installed the VirtualBox, but it is... ridiculous if this is the reason.

See the screenshot for what happens when I right-click.

[image]

Comment: Have you used any registry cleaners like CCleaner recently? Any program of the sort?

Comment: @Insane I ran my antivirus (PSafe Total) recently and he have a feature "Clear space", like CCleaner. But as this can cause this problem?

Comment: Registry cleaners can cause problems and usually do more harm than good. I researched your issue a bit and it seemed to be due to missing and or damaged registry keys. That's why I asked

Comment: Well, I not found a good solution for this problem. I'm resetting my system. Thanks for explain. I will try not run a disk cleaner again.

Comment: He said "Registry Cleaner" NOT "Disk Cleaner". Disk cleaners are okay. Like Windows's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following steps.

1. Open Registry Editor. To open it search for 'regedit' in Taskbar search box.
2. The navigate to the following path in Registry: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
3. Now create a key named `New` under ContextMenuHandlers
4. Set its default value to the following in right side plane: 
   {D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}
5. Restart the system and check again